# Can I share a network folder on WinPE (Windows Preinstallation Enviroment)

Tags: shared-folders, winpe

Is it possible to create a shared folder on WinPE?
It has powershell and wifi installed on it.

Comment: Yes; It’s possible.  What have you tried?  The same command to setup a shared location from a command line within Windows works on WinPE.  Update your question please.

Comment: Ok, I am surprised, I thought the commands used were missing. I will try them next I have access to do so

Answer (score 0):

1. Start command prompt, usually with <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd> or by selecting cmd in advanced menu
2. Start server service execution and confirm it's running: `net share`
3. Set administrator password: `net user administrator <super_pass>`
4. Disable firewall: `Wpeutil DisableFirewall`
5. Get your IP address: `ipconfig`

Now you can connect by using Windows Explorer `\\IP\c$` as administrator
or `smb://IP/c$` for macOS.